# cannot load such file -- rake/file_list (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, rubygems

I’m having an issue that I’m struggling to fix.
For some reason, any rails command I’m trying to run in the terminal isn’t working.
I keep on getting this error message

> /Users/Sebastien/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require’: cannot load such file -- rake/file_list (LoadError)

Has anyone experienced this before? Stackoverflow didn’t help :(

Answer (score 0):

Try filename.load once, as i can't comment because of low reputation